# How to use AT command to detect phone line is busy

Tags: modem, at-command

I have a USB modem. Is it possible to detect the phone line is busy or not?

I thought I could use AT Command to detect dial tone, but I'm not sure are there any commands support that.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean "phone line is in use or not?"  Two different things.

Comment: yes, I mean "phone line is use or not", sorry for my poor English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to do this the same as a human would... take it off hook and wait for dial tone.

Ripped from http://michaelgellis.tripod.com/modem.html

> D alone will take the modem off-hook and wait for a dial tone. (see
>   X command for exceptions). The length of time to wait for a dial tone
>   before dialing is programmable in register S6.

Answer (score 0):

If you try call, and it's busy, modem send you message `BUSY` or `NO ANSWER`

Comment: thanks for you help!! My modem is just monitoring the phone line (receiving CallerID signal), so if I try call, it may disturb some users. Are there any other ways? thanks